# Show recommended articles based on the current article being read

Tags: channel, recommendation-request

The title is pretty self-explanatory, but I have a website which has dozens of articles based on healthcare in the US, each sort of categorised by the type of insurance. At the moment I have a sidebar which shows the four "latest" articles.. however, this can be seen as pretty irrelevant for many readers.

How could I create a list of URLs to the most relevant articles? I.e. if a user is reading up on Medigap, a recommended article could be Medigap costs explained

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way would be the native related category mode within EE. https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#related-categories-mode

But that depends on how granular you get with categories, or the matches may still be undesirable.

Beyond that a plugin allowing you to tag your content then output related entries based on the tag data, like eeHarbour's Tag addon, would work.
https://eeharbor.com/tag

However, that will require you go back and tag existing content. But it is better than native categories for many uses IMO.